# Which is the correct phrase to use? On the app or to the app

Tags: prepositions, sentence

The context is "What kind of a book can be added **on the app**/ **to the app**?"
When I typed the sentence "What kind of a book can be added **on the app**?" on Grammarly
it was autocorrected "What kind of a book can be added **to the app**?"

Comment: Grammarly is not smart enough to know the difference between "on the" and "to the" in context. It does recognize that "added to" is much more common than "added on". (And I don't think "added" is the correct word, I'd use "put on the app".)

Comment: It's not clear what "on the app" or "to the app" mean, without any context - it could mean loading books into the app (like with an e-reader/Kindle); adding books to a list of everything you've read on the app; buying a book through the app (but reading it elsewhere); publishing a book or putting a book up for sale on the app...

Answer (score 0):

The lack of context is confusing the issue. Asking “What kind of book?” usually has the reply “detective, historical novel, horror, children’s, classic, reference, etc.”

With both examples, you probably not talking about “kind of book” but “the kind of file format in which the book appears”, i.e. you mean “In the case of books, which file formats can the app read?”

"What kind of a book can be added **on** the app?"= "What format of book can be added **by use of** or **whilst you are using** the app?" (added is

"What kind of a book can be added **to** the app?"= "What format of a book can be **used as an addition/accessory** to the app?" – this does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: I have to disagree. In context, it's completely clear that "what kind of book" means what format of book, and there's nothing wrong or confusing about that phrasing.